# Label Expressions to replace null values with text not in feature class

Tags: arcmap, labeling

I need to label some hydrants (points) - some of these belong to the fire brigade and have a number assigned to them, some do not and thus do not have a number. I would like to write an expression along the lines of:

'Label Hydrant with number if number exists, if hydrant has null value label with 'WO'.'

I just can't figure it out.

The simplest way for me to do this would be to change the null values to WO but the data is not mine, and I do not want to make changes to it. I suppose I could make a copy and put the values in the copy, but ideally I would like an expression.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Think I'm still missing something this is what I am doing: _1._ Tick Label features in the layer _2._ Select 'Define classes of features and label each class differently _3._ Add label Class Number _4._ Add Label Class WO _5._ tick 'label features in this class' for each <br/> 6. Under 'Number' click SQL Query use ("SYMBOLCODE"  = 3 ) AND ( "FIREAUTHOR" <> "") _7._ Label field is set to FIREAUTHOR _8._ For WO SQL is ("SYMBOLCODE"  = 3 ) AND ("FIREAUTHOR" ="")  _9._ Expression is "WO" _10._ Get error 'no features found. Could not verify expression'

Answer (score 9):

You can use a simple script like this to label the features with Null values.

```
Function FindLabel ( [yourfield] )
  if isnull( [yourfield]) then
    FindLabel = "WO"
  else
    FindLabel = [yourfield]
  end if
End Function
```

Comment: It's great to see you on gis.se. Your answers on the ESRI forums have helped a lot of people, including me.

Comment: Thanks - this script is certainly neat, but  the null values are not being labelled as WO.

Comment: Are you working with values that are showing up as <Null> or as blanks in the attribute table?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do.

1. Set up two labeling classes under the labeling tab under the Method: Define clases of features and label each class differently.
2. Create a hydrant class that has numbers and one that does not (e.g. Number, & WO).
3. For the number class define the SQL Query as, "MyLabelField" <> ""
4. Point the number class to the correct label field.
5. For the WO class define the SQL Query as, "MyLabelField" = ""
6. For the WO class under the Expression option type, "WO"
7. Turn labeling on.

Answer (score 3):

Further to @kenbuja sript which is the correct answer;
If you have a combination of null and 0 length strings or spaces with no characters you could do something like this:

```
Function FindLabel ( [LABELFIELD] )
  if  isnull([LABELFIELD]) then
    FindLabel = "WO"
  elseif trim([LABELFIELD]) = "" then
    FindLabel = "WO"
  else
    FindLabel = ucase([LABELFIELD])
  end if
End Function
```